# What are bonds in molten NaCl?

Tags: bond

I know there are ionic bonds in solid NaCl. But what bonds are present in liquid (molten) NaCl? I believe there should be some kind of attraction there, because particles (ions) are pretty close to each other. What are these attractions?

Comment: Those are ionic bonds.

Comment: You mean, ionic bonds do not get broken when NaCl gets molten?

Comment: I did not say that. Rather, they break and form readily, which is why they can move past each other, which is why it is called a liquid.

Comment: Energy should be released at the moment of formation a new ionic bond, so in this way this process should be exothermic. As we heat NaCl at that time (in order to make it molten), so we supply energy, and temperature is high, it is difficult to imagine successful exothermic process under this conditions.

Comment: View it as a dynamic equilibrium, where the bond-forming exothermic processes and the bond-breaking endothermic processes balance out each other.

Comment: You could ask same thing about water; there's h-bonding in ice and liquid, what else would there be?

Comment: So what is the difference between inter-molecular bonding in ice and water? Apparently they look different: solid vs. liquid.