# What is the structure of sodium chloride in the liquid state?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ionic-compounds

I understand that sodium chloride when solid, is a lattice, so NaCl there is an empirical formula,(so, expresses that the ratio of Na to Cl is 1-1), and not a molecular formula expressing exact numbers of atoms.

I was looking at this question which covers what sodium chloride is like in gas state. [What is Sodium Chloride like in gas state?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14174/what-is-sodium-chloride-like-in-gas-state/)

And it mentions that in gas form, you get an NaCl monomer, and $\ce{Na2Cl2}$ dimer. That's mentioned in the abstract https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp073328o. And those are molecules, not like with the sodium chloride lattice.

But what about for sodium chloride as liquid. What form does sodium chloride take there?

Comment: @OscarLanzi so would you say it's not a monomer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomer  or dimer? (or would you say that a monomer or a dimer, isn't necessarily a molecule)?

Comment: You can certainly have monomeric ion pairs.

Comment: A good starting point to check is https://moltensalt.org/whatIsMoltenSalt.html. It is essentially high-temperature ionic liquid, whereas the topical room-temperature ionic liquid (RTIL) is essentially ambient-temperature molten salt. I think a key property to understand the ion associations in molten salt is radial distribution function. There are lots of molecular dynamics simulations, even from decades ago.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Well, I would sure call them molecules. Ion pairs are in cases like here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136299/what-happens-to-boiled-bmimpf6

Comment: More to the point, liquid NaCl isn't much different then solid, but average coordination number is lower.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136857/when-you-melt-an-ionic-compound-do-you-break-its-electrostatic-force-of-attra

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59462/what-are-bonds-in-molten-nacl

Comment: For an answer you might want to look at Karsten Theis's answer in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136857/when-you-melt-an-ionic-compound-do-you-break-its-electrostatic-force-of-attra for instance.